# How to pass text from gets.chomp to a file

Tags: ruby

I want to push `resources :#{get}` to the bottom of `resources :posts`.

```
get = gets.chomp
@file = File.open('config/routes.rb','r+')
myString = "
  resources :#{get}s
"

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :posts
  end
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

The result is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :posts
    resources :categories
  end
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

How do I pass data from user input to a file?

Comment: This smells like an [*X-Y problem*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/2988) to me: you have problem X, and you *think* the solution is Y, but you run into a problem implementing Y, and now you are asking about your problem with implementing Y, instead of how to solve your problem X. You are asking "how to pass data from user input to a file", but it looks like what you *really* want to do is generate Rails routes?

Comment: infect I know about my title because stack overflow not allow me to put the title similar to other content so I have no choice because other problem not

Comment: the same with my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the assumption that there will only ever be one `resources :posts` in your routes file, a simple example could be done like:

```ruby
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/inflections' # for `pluralize`

get = gets.chomp
lines = File.read("config/routes.rb").split(/\n/)

# find the line of the file we want to insert after. This assumes
# there will only be a single `resources :posts` in your routes.
index = lines.index { |line| line.strip == 'resources :posts' }
# duplicate the existing line and replace 'posts' with the pluralized form
# of whatever the user input to gets, we do it this way to keep indentation
new_line = lines[index].gsub(/posts/, get.pluralize)

# insert the new line on the line after the `resources :posts` and then write
# the entire thing back out to 'config/routes.rb'
lines.insert(index + 1, new_line)
File.open("config/routes.rb", "w") { |f| f.write(lines.join("\n")) }
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, though, you may find it useful to look into [Rails Generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html).

**before**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

**execute**

```
$ echo category | ruby example.rb
```

**after**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :posts
    resources :categories
  end
end
```